# Strange behavior of systimestamp and sysdate

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle18c

Today I encountered a situation which I can not explain and I hope you can.

It boils down to this:

Let say `function sleep() return number;` loops for 10 seconds and then returns 1.

A sql query like

```
SELECT systimestamp s1, sleep(), systimestamp s2 from dual;
```

Will result in two identical values for s1 and s2. So this is somewhat optimized.

A PLSQL-Block with

```
a_timestamp := systimestamp + 5sec;
IF systimestamp < a_timestamp and sleep() = 1 and systimestamp > a_timestamp THEN 
  [...] 
END IF;
```

will evaluate to true, because the expression get evaluated from left to right and because of the sleep() the second systimestamp is 10sec greater than the first and a_timestamp lies between both. The +5sec syntax is pseudo code, but bear with me. So here the systimestamp is not optimized.

But now it gets funky:

```
IF systimestamp between systimestamp and systimestamp THEN [...]
```

Is always false, but

```
IF systimestamp + 0 between systimestamp + 0 and systimestamp + 0 THEN [...]
```

Is always true.

Why? I am confused...

This happens with sysdate as well

Comment: [Are you sure](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=528c58224d3865f9d5994c7c7bbcd290)? The only way I get false is with `systimestamp between systimestamp + 0 and systimestamp + 0` (rather than `systtimestamp + 0 between...`). Which is expected as the data type changes (unless you get really lucky and the fractional seconds happen to be exactly zero anyway). Otherwise it gets true. Can you reproduce what you're seeing in a fiddle?

Comment: Hi Alex, you are right. I swapped the results. Without an addition it's always false: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=69037977212e77191009ece88286aebf

Comment: I have 18c, I tested it and I have true in both cases. I'm quite sure that Oracle compiler makes optimization and both systimestamp and systimestamp + 0 are calculated just one time, so in both cases it will be always true.

Comment: @Obenland - the third and fourth blocks in your version are expected, again because of the datatype change. The first one is interesting though. If it is evaluiating systimestamp three separate times then it could still be true on a fast enough system with low precision (milliseconds), but even then probably not always.

Comment: @Vladimir.V.Bvn - the SQL compiler does that optimisation; the PL/SQL compiler doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
if systimestamp between systimestamp and systimestamp then
```

the non-deterministic `systimestamp` call is just being evaluated three times, and getting very slightly different results each time.

You can see the same effect with

```
if systimestamp >= systimestamp then
```

which also always returns false.

Except, it's not quite always. If the server is fast enough and/or the platform it's on has low-enough precision for timestamp fractional seconds (i.e. on Windows, which I believe still limits the precision to milliseconds) then all of those calls could still get the same value some or most of the time.

Things are a bit different in SQL; as an equivalent:

```
select *
from dual
where systimestamp between systimestamp and systimestamp;
```

will always return a row, so the condition is always true. That is [explicitly mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-5652DBC2-41C7-4F07-BEDD-DAF620E35F3C):

> All of the datetime functions that return current system datetime information, such as SYSDATE, SYSTIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, and so forth, are evaluated once for each SQL statement, regardless how many times they are referenced in that statement.

There is no such restriction/optimisation (depending on how you look at it) in PL/SQL. When you use `between` [it does say](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-B748E382-B068-48EC-B809-4FAB1F8D7C6B):

> The value of the expression x BETWEEN a AND b is defined to be the same as the value of the expression (x>=a) AND (x<=b) . The expression x will only be evaluated once.

and the SQL reference [also mentions that](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/BETWEEN-Condition.html#GUID-868A7C9D-EDF9-44E7-91B5-C3F69E503CCB):

> In SQL, it is possible that *expr1* will be evaluated more than once. If the BETWEEN expression appears in PL/SQL, *expr1* is guaranteed to be evaluated only once.

but it says nothing about skipping evaluation of *a* and *b* (or *expr2* or *expr3*) even for system datetime functions in PL/SQL.

So all three expressions in your `between` will be evaluated, it will make three separate calls to `systimestamp`, and they will all (usually) get slightly different results. You effectively end up with:

```
if initial_time between initial_time + 1 microsecond and initial_time + 2 microseconds then
```

or to put it another way

```
if (initial_time >= initial_time + 1 microsecond) and (initial_time <= initial_time + 2 microseconds) then
```

While `(initial_time <= initial_time + 2 microseconds)` is always going to be true, `(initial_time >= initial_time + 1 microsecond)` has to be false - unless the interval between the first and third evaluations is actually zero for that platform/server/invocation. When it is zero the condition evaluates to true; the rest of the time, when there is any measurable delay, it will evaluate to false.

---

Your other examples all manipulate the timestamp in way that removes the fractional seconds, by turning some or all of the results into dates, as @Connor showed (and I alluded to in comments). Those aren't really relevant to your core question of why `if systimestamp between systimestamp and systimestamp then` is (usually) false.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! 

Answer (score 1):

If you add a number to a timestamp, you do not get a timestamp...you get a date.  Thus you have lopped off the fractional seconds part, and thus comparisons that *look* like they should be equal might not be

```
SQL> select systimestamp, systimestamp+0 from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP                                                                SYSTIMESTAMP+0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------
18-JUN-20 11.57.28.350000 AM +08:00                                         18/06/2020 11:57:28

SQL> select * from dual where systimestamp > sysdate;

D
-
X
```

If you want to add days etc to a timestamp, use an INTERVAL data type not a NUMBER.